# Synonym for 'learnings'

Tags: synonyms

What is a synonym for the term 'learnings', as in 'learnings from a research project'?

I thought of 'conclusions', but I am looking for a broader term.

Comment: What about "inferences"- deriving logical conclusions from premises known or assumed to be true. (wiki)

Comment: Nice, I like that one as well! @mystisinha

Comment: In some contexts (likely not the one you mention, though), I might use "lessons". I would never use "learnings".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A synonym for this would be findings.

Answer (score 11):

I would first submit that "learnings" is highly irregular, and you probably want to avoid its usage.

> A good word here for you would be "**findings**" if you want a similar word that seems to suggest a broader scope when compared to conclusions (which is not a synonym at any rate).

Answer (score 5):

In a research project we have **"results"** which is a detailed account of what has been found, and **"conclusions"** where you present a summarized review of the results and add whatever implications they have for practical application, or further studies.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that the correct word for "learnings" is *lessons*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure "learnings" is one of those annoying corporate-speak words — like the word "actionable" — just vague enough to possibly mean nothing at all. I hear it all the time in business meetings! I like to just say "what I learned was...."

Answer (score 1):

You could use "takeaway," but that's somewhat informal. You'd be better off using it in speech than in writing.